# Effect of using std::stringbuf for buffering while performing a write via insertion operator '<<'

Tags: c++, performance, buffer, fstream

I am trying to benchmark the effects of manual buffering (via `std::stringbuf`) on the running time while performing a write to a file as opposed to buffering done by the insertion operator `<<`.

### Version 1 (without manual buffering)

This version involves performing a write at each iteration.

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("output_file", std::ios::out);

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
  ofs << "Hello world!\n";
```

**Time:** 2.83s user 1.14s system 28% cpu 13.918 total

### Version 2 (with manual buffering)

This version buffers the entire data in `std::string` object before finally writing it.

```
std::string buffer;
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("output_file", std::ios::out);

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
  buffer.append("Hello world!\n");

ofs << buffer;
```

**Time:** 1.87s user 2.27s system 24% cpu 16.654 total

There is an observable difference between the running times of version 1 and 2, and similar behavior was observed in different runs. How is it the case that the second version ends up being slower when it only performs a single write operation as opposed to multiple writes in first ?
This result is also in contrast with the results posted in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12997131/5107319), however the current case is a slight variation of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't "only perform a single write operation"; you are not considering the cost of building up that string, which is not zero.

You may find that a `buffer.reserve(100000000 * strlen("Hello world!\n"))` helps things a little.