# std::ofstream - no buffering string longer than 1023 (instant flush)

Tags: c++, buffer, fstream, ofstream

When I changed size of `ofstream` buffer with `pubsetbuf(...)`, everything works fine, except when I put to `ofstream` single string longer then `1023` (in the code below). Is it correct behavior or I did something wrong?

```
int main(){
    std::vector<char> rawBuf;
    std::ofstream stream;

    rawBuf.resize(20000);
    stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(&rawBuf[0], 20000);

    stream.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::app);

    std::string data(1499, 'b');

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   
        stream << data.substr(0, 1024) << "\n"; //1023-length string works great
        sleep(1);
    }
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

when there is 1024-length string `strace ./program` shows something like this:

```
writev(3, [{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 1024
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffcf3889ac0) = 0
writev(3, [{iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 1025
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffcf3889ac0) = 0
... and so on 10x
```

when there is 1023-length string, everything seems ok:

```
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff8e13a980) = 0
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff8e13a980) = 0
... 10x
```

and then:

```
write(3, "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"..., 10240) = 10240
```

Why here is single write and earlier is not?

edit:

```
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
```

Comment: The disk buffer is handled by the operative system, not the programming language. Moreover (I am not sure, but), other cache mechanisms (e.g., hardware) can occur.

Comment: @BiagioFesta if I understand it correctly, rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(..) is not about disk buffer, but internal buffer of stream (isn't it different for every stream?)

Comment: Please add to question: OS Version (probably some Linux), compiler version (probably gcc). This is definitely compiler standard library issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [[filebuf.virtuals]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf.virtuals#12):

> ```
> basic_streambuf* setbuf(char_type* s, streamsize n) override;
> ```
>
> *Effects:* If `setbuf(0, 0)` is called on a stream before any I/O has occurred on that stream, the stream becomes unbuffered. Otherwise the
>   results are implementation-defined. “Unbuffered” means that `pbase()`
>   and `pptr()` always return null and output to the file should appear
>   as soon as possible.

“Implementation-defined” includes “works fine” and “there is only a single write” and other things.  In fact, here's what libstdc++ 7.3.0 [says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/streambufs.html#io.streambuf.buffering):

> First, are you sure that you understand buffering? Particularly the
>   fact that C++ may not, in fact, have anything to do with it?
>
> The rules for buffering can be a little odd, but they aren't any
>   different from those of C. (Maybe that's why they can be a bit odd.)
>   Many people think that writing a newline to an output stream
>   automatically flushes the output buffer. This is true only when the
>   output stream is, in fact, a terminal and not a file or some other
>   device -- and that may not even be true since C++ says nothing about
>   files nor terminals. All of that is system-dependent. (The
>   "newline-buffer-flushing only occurring on terminals" thing is mostly
>   true on Unix systems, though.)
>
> Some people also believe that sending endl down an output stream only
>   writes a newline. This is incorrect; after a newline is written, the
>   buffer is also flushed. Perhaps this is the effect you want when
>   writing to a screen -- get the text out as soon as possible, etc --
>   but the buffering is largely wasted when doing this to a file:
>
> ```
> output << "a line of text" << endl;
> output << some_data_variable << endl;
> output << "another line of text" << endl;
> ```
>
> The proper thing to do in this case to just write the data out and let
>   the libraries and the system worry about the buffering. If you need a
>   newline, just write a newline:
>
> ```
> output << "a line of text\n"
>  << some_data_variable << '\n'
>  << "another line of text\n";
> ```
>
> I have also joined the output statements into a single statement. You
>   could make the code prettier by moving the single newline to the start
>   of the quoted text on the last line, for example.
>
> If you do need to flush the buffer above, you can send an `endl` if
>   you also need a newline, or just flush the buffer yourself:
>
> ```
> output << ...... << flush;    // can use std::flush manipulator
> output.flush();               // or call a member fn
> ```
>
> On the other hand, there are times when writing to a file should be
>   like writing to standard error; no buffering should be done because
>   the data needs to appear quickly (a prime example is a log file for
>   security-related information). The way to do this is just to turn off
>   the buffering before any I/O operations at all have been done (note
>   that opening counts as an I/O operation):
>
> ```
> std::ofstream    os;
> std::ifstream    is;
> int   i;
>
> os.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0,0);
> is.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0,0);
>
> os.open("/foo/bar/baz");
> is.open("/qux/quux/quuux");
> ...
> os << "this data is written immediately\n";
> is >> i;   // and this will probably cause a disk read
> ```
>
> Since all aspects of buffering are handled by a `streambuf`-derived
>   member, it is necessary to get at that member with `rdbuf()`. Then the
>   public version of `setbuf` can be called. The arguments are the same
>   as those for the Standard C I/O Library function (a buffer area
>   followed by its size).
>
> A great deal of this is implementation-dependent. For example,
>   `streambuf` does not specify any actions for its own `setbuf()`-ish
>   functions; the classes derived from `streambuf` each define behavior
>   that "makes sense" for that class: an argument of `(0,0)` turns off
>   buffering for `filebuf` but does nothing at all for its siblings
>   `stringbuf` and `strstreambuf`, and specifying anything other than
>   `(0,0)` has varying effects. User-defined classes derived from
>   `streambuf` can do whatever they want. (For `filebuf` and arguments
>   for `(p,s)` other than zeros, libstdc++ does what you'd expect: the
>   first `s` bytes of `p` are used as a buffer, which you must allocate
>   and deallocate.)
>
> A last reminder: there are usually more buffers involved than just
>   those at the language/library level. Kernel buffers, disk buffers, and
>   the like will also have an effect. Inspecting and changing those are
>   system-dependent.

Comment: thanks, this led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585805/11728427) and there is what i want to know about std::basic_filebuf: "**By default it uses 1024 bytes buffer (BUFSIZ variable)**". It was reported to GCC in 2014... so it seems the only way to buffer longer strings is make them smaller.